# Open PDF when USB is plugged in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, pdf, usb-flash-drive, autorun

I have a PDF file on an USB drive (named test.pdf placed in root). How do I get it to open automatically as soon as I plug in the USB drive? No dialog or anything, just open the PDF directly after the UBS drive is plugged in.

Windows 7 and autorun.inf is not working for me.

Comment: Not on Windows 7, sorry. MS removed this functionality so people can't autorun virus's or the like!

Comment: You might find this useful: http://superuser.com/questions/659649/start-a-action-when-a-usb-device-is-added

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us what your autorun.inf looks like? Just as a sanity check, it should be:

```
[autorun]
open=autorun.exe
icon=autorun.ico
```

If it is formatted correctly, then it is possible that the OS is ignoring/overriding it's request. I've seen that happen a number of times.

Check control panel and see what the autoplay settings are and try **disabling** autorun. Follow this link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/autoplay-not-working-for-usb-flash-drive/304f3ddd-13a1-44a9-be5a-1e9f4c74b3a9

EDIT:

1. It seems Win 7 doesn't allow this anymore http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/autorun-inf-does-not-work-in-windows-7-anymore/

It is a good decision imo since several XP machines were affected by autorun.inf "viruses"

.. you could always write a script to do it for you